# Check file exists or not using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I stored a file path in database table like this `../Document/5292013/cal.png`. Now I want to check whether or not the file exists in the server folder. I am using the below code to check this, but it's not working for me.

```
 if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(root.GetElementsByTagName("FLD_DOC_ID")[0].InnerText)))
 {
     proof.HRef = Server.MapPath(root.GetElementsByTagName("FLD_DOC_ID")[0].InnerText);
 }
```

Now I check using watch `File.Exists(Server.MapPath("Document")) //Returns false`, but server having the same folder.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting an error? Are you not finding the file?

Comment: it returns always false

Comment: can you show the folder structure of your web application ?

Comment: Document/somename/xx.png

Comment: For map path to work correctly, you should start your path with `~`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transform the file name to a virtual form before using `MapPath`. You must know  the specifics of how it needs to be done. For example:

```
string fileName = root.GetElementsByTagName("FLD_DOC_ID")[0].InnerText;
fileName = fileName.Replace("..", "~");
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(fileName))
{
    // you probably do not want MapPath here:
    //proof.HRef = Server.MapPath(root.GetElementsByTagName("FLD_DOC_ID")[0].InnerText);
    proof.HRef = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to print out Server.MapPath(root.GetElementsByTagName("FLD_DOC_ID")[0].InnerText)
it might be pointing a wrong path or something

Any way, checking a file if it exists or not is very trivial:

```
if(File.Exists(the file path))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get filepath (filename) from database using select query then use that path with file.exists.

Example:

First get filename or filepath from database then,

if you get only filename then use below code:

```
if(File.Exits(Server.MapPath("Document/5292013/"+filename)))
{
}
```

or 
if you get only filepath then use below code:

```
if(File.Exits(Server.MapPath("filename")))
{
}
```

Thanks